# TextBox Placeholder text while also Binding to ListBox.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, .net, binding, microsoft-metro

How can I still have a Placeholder text (.Text = "Whatever") while also binding the textbox to a ListBox's Selected Item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When do you want this placeholder text to display? When there is no SelectedItem?

You could use [PriorityBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx) which will allow you to provide a list of bindings and it will use the first that produces a result.

Something like:

```
<TextBox> 
   <TextBox.Text>
     <PriorityBinding>
       <Binding Path="myListBox.SelectedItem"/>
       <Binding Source="Default Text"/>
     </PriorityBinding>
   </TextBox.text>
 </TextBox>
```

Comment: :O - Great idea! Thanks @Richard :) (and yep, only when there's no selected item/a new item is being added that hasn't already been given a title)

Comment: Check out my edit, not sure if my first suggestion would work in hindsight, as it would depend on SelectedItem being non-existent (causing the binding to fail) rather than just null... Using a PriorityBinding should address this.

Comment: Uh oh, seems like PriorityBinding won't work. Is there an alternative?`PriorityBinding is not supported in a Windows Metro style project.`

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, I've never played with a Metro style project! How about a TargetNullValue on the binding ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx)?

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how you guys manage to find the docs that I can't find! Thanks, that solved it :)

Comment: hahaha, it's the bitter curse of having had the same problem before! =) No worries mate, glad it helped.